# Sending Form without changing url page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Here is the deal:
I manage to get this sendmail.php working by creating 2 html pages redirecting to index.
But what i wanted is that (if($sent) == true) to appear a alert on the html form page that the message as been sent. but when i change

`{echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = '/sent.html';</script>";}`
 to

```
{echo "<script language=javascript>window.alert = 'Message Sent';</script>";}
```

the page redirects to ...url...com/sendmail.php as blank

It is live @ www.aroundgalaxy.pt/NEW

here is the form html

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <div class="row half">
            <div class="6u">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row half">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="text" class="text" name="subject" placeholder="Assunto" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row half">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Messagem"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Enviar" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the sendmail.php

```
<?php
$to = "info@aroundgalaxy.pt";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
//$site = $_REQUEST['site'] ;
$subject = "Message from: $name";
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$headers = "noreply@aroundgalaxy.pt";
$body = "From: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Message: $message";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
if($sent)
{echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = '/sent.html';</script>";}
else
{echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = '/notsent.html';</script>";}
?>
```

Comment: Combine the HTML & PHP into one file then POST the form to itself

Comment: @meda placing the php code in the html file?

Comment: Why don't you use `header('Location: /sent.html')` for your redirects?

Comment: why dont you use ajax?

Comment: @raheelshan any benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alert() not alert =.

```
{echo "<script language=javascript>window.alert('Message Sent');</script>";}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working. syntax error hehe
{echo "<script language=javascript>
alert('Mensagem enviada');
window.location = 'index.html';</script>";}

Answer (score 1):

If you want alternative try this:

In a sendmail.php add following:

`sendmail.php:`

```
setcookie("msg","Mail Successfully Sent",time()+5,"/");
header("location:htmlpage.php");
```

and in `htmlpage.php`

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['msg'])){?>
<div>
    <?php echo $_COOKIE['msg'];setcookie("msg","",time()-5,"/");?>  
</div>
<?php }?>
```